# Kafka transactions - why do I need to replicate?

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions

I am using Kafka for a circular buffer of the last 24 hours of events.

I have 4 brokers that are run on on ephemeral cloud providers. So the disk is local, if the broker dies I loose the data for that broker. I can start the broker again and it an replicate the data from another broker. I have replicas setup for my topic and the offsets topic:

```
default.replication.factor=2
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
```

I'm using transactions to commit the new offsets + new records atomically. My app is side affect free, so if the transaction fails, I can poll and get the same records and repeat the processing and produce the same resultant events.

So the defaults for the transaction durability properties:

```
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
```

I feel that in my setup, I can set both of these properties to `1` i.e. no replication/durability (as my app is side affect free). Yet I can't shake the niggling feeling for some reason that I'm wrong.

Am I wrong? Why are the transactions durable in the first place - what scenario does the durability help with?

Comment: I don't see how you'd recover any data if you set replication to 1, and that broker dies. Unless you're trying to save space, offsets topic replication should be 3 or more, by the way (esp if it has min ISR of 2)

Comment: @OneCricketeer - for transactions its set to `1`...if the broker that is coordinating the transaction dies, the client can start a new transaction poll the same records again, produce the same new records and attempt to commit those along with the offsets in the new transaction - processing of events is side-effect free. My aim is to reduce latency.

Comment: If your transaction topic is unavailable, transactional client requests would start failing, AFAIK

Comment: @OneCricketeer - that's a fair point, if the broker doesn't get restarted, then the transactions will fail.

Comment: that sounds like the answer you're looking for... I've personally not tested it, but should be easy to.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - sort of I can set the transaction replication factor = 2 and transaction min isr to 1...but that doesn't help me answer the question at the bottom of the OP.